# Swizzling of a function - and function known at runtime only

Tags: ios, objective-c, method-swizzling, libffi

I want to swizzle a function in objective-c. The problem is that - I know the function that needs to be swizzled only at runtime. Now different methods in the code will have different return types, input params etc.

How should I write a (generic) code that, if given the name of the function and class to which it belong, I can create a block and then use imp_implementationWithBlock to create IMP and then swizzle original method with this newly created IMP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSSelectorFromString()` to dynamically look up a selector name and then perform the swizzling. There are many helpers so I don't need to repeat the exact swizzling logic. E.g. if you use [Aspects](https://github.com/steipete/Aspects) the code could look like this:

```
[_singleTapGesture aspect_hookSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"setState:") withOptions:AspectPositionAfter usingBlock:^(id<AspectInfo> aspectInfo) {
    NSLog(@"%@: %@", aspectInfo.instance, aspectInfo.arguments);
} error:NULL];
```

For runtime-swizzling you should make sure you know what you're doing and fail gracefully if the selector does not exist.

Comment: lets say, I have a function foo which is throwing an exception. I want to surround the body of this function with a try-catch block. 

Thus, I need to make a block from this function foo and the block must have exactly same signature. This block will have a try-catch between which I will call the original method. After which, I will swizzle the original code to new block.

Thus any further calls to foo will go through a try-catch implemented in the block.

I am not able to create a block at runtime because, I do not know about its arguments and return type at compile time.

Comment: Aspects provide only before, after and instead - I need to surround it with try-catch, is there a way to do that using Aspects?

Comment: Also, how would this block in example would take the arguments to the function? we need to supply that in usingBlock.

Comment: You can easily wrap it with using the Instead option and then calling the original implementation - see AspectInfo and the README in the repo.